# jQuery not showing correctly in aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get this function to work in an aspx page but I'm having a rotten time.  Basically it works fine in a regular HTML page but in the aspx page, when click on the button all you can see is a sliver of the top part and on occasion (every 5th+ single button click & every double click) the message shows and fades like it should.  What am I missing?  Could it be getting tied up in the postback?

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/Xthgh/)

Code using in aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="checkTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.checkTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#Button1").click(function () {
                    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .message{height:70px;display:none;}
        .noChangesMessage{width:84px;padding:8px 8px;  background:#535353; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:white;text-align:center;}
        .tipEnd{width:0;height:0;border-left:10px solid transparent;border-right:10px solid transparent;border-top:10px solid #535353;margin:0 auto;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">



    <br /><br /><br />
    <div>
    <div style="width:100px">
    <div style="height:70px">            
                <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" class="message">
                    <div class="noChangesMessage">No changes were made!</div>
                    <div class="tipEnd"></div>
                </div></div>
            <div style="">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save Changes"  />
            </div>
            </div> 

    </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my code via view source for amit_g

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#Button1").click(function () {
                    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">.
    .message{height:70px;display:none;}
        .noChangesMessage{width:84px;padding:8px 8px;  background:#535353; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; color:white;text-align:center;}
        .tipEnd{width:0;height:0;border-left:10px solid transparent;border-right:10px solid transparent;border-top:10px solid #535353;margin:0 auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="checkTest.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjA0OTM4MTAwNGRkU+SP3bu4QJNH9S9XtdwPbEE8YODY/YlkotOt6l692s8=" />
</div>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKroLr3AwKM54rGBtLTfCTwYmYnb6l8tnp5jtojhvORYMJ6bPzAI+qbaDlU" />
</div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div>
    <div style="width:100px">
    <div style="height:70px">            
                <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" class="message">
                    <div class="noChangesMessage">No changes were made!</div>
                    <div class="tipEnd"></div>
                </div></div>
            <div style="">
                <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Save Changes" id="Button1" class="Button1" /></div>
            </div>   
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the rendered code (view source in the browser) and use that in the fiddler or post here.

Comment: @amit_g see above for added code via view source

Comment: This is most likely because the form is submitted. Should the postback happen when this button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {    
   $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);}
);
```

Comment: you are missing the $ for `$(".message")`

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with asp.net dynamically naming html elements, one way you can get the Id value is to use clientId something like Button1.clinetId

```
 $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
});
```

it's that simple

Comment: you are missing the $ for `$(".message")`

Comment: No prob Bob! LoL ... had to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The button click is triggering a postback, which causes a reload of the page.  Your animation is cancelled before it has a chance to play out (barring random delays).

ASP.NET Webforms attaches an event handler to the button click event which triggers javascript that is dynamically generated for your page.  This is the central mechanism for interactive pages in webforms.

Comment: So how would I call the function so that it doesn't trigger a post back so the animation doesn't cancel out?

Answer (score 0):

I see the answers where they have changed the id to a class in order to properly select the button.

Personally, I don't like to change code to address issues like this, since the ID is required by the ASP.NET control we might as well target it.

The best way that I have found to select .NET controls, as their IDs are prepended at run time, is to use the 'ending in' selector.

```
$("[id$='Button1']").click(function () {
    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
});
```

Comment: you are missing the $ for `$(".message")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Master / Content pages, but if so, what I've found that works is giving your Master / Content pages an ID.

If you are simply using one of each, and assuming you give the Master page an ID of "Mstr" and the Content page an ID of "Cont", you could create JavaScript prefixes like so:

```
var masterPrefix = "Mstr_",
    contentPrefix = "Cont_";
```

Then, you could create a function called `$getElement()` that would allow you to pass the ID that you give in your markup like so:

```
function $getElement(id) {
    return $("#" + masterPrefix + contentPrefix + id);
}
```

Then, given your specific example, you could get a jQuery object to your runat="server" div by doing the following:

```
var $button = $getElement("Button1");

$button.click(function() {
    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
});
```

I've found this method to be a life saver when you get into large projects that have heavy client-side scripting.

Alternatively, if you don't like calling another function to return your object, you could always do this:

```
var $button = $('input[id$="Button1"]');

$button.click(function() {
    $(".message").stop(true,true).slideToggle().fadeOut(6000);
});
```

Here you are just saying give me the div who has an ID ending in "Button1".